# Angular 4 - @HostBinding bind the css class to host element but ui not rending correctly.

Tags: angular

I have created ProductListComponent and it access the child component ProductRowComponent. The code listed below

ProductListComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
 import { Product } from '../product';
  @Component({
      selector: 'products-list',
      template: `
          <product-row *ngFor="let myProduct of productList"
                        [product]="myProduct"
                        (click)="clicked(myProduct)"
                        [class.selectedItem] = "isSelected(myProduct)">
          </product-row>
      `
    })
    export class ProductsListComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() productList: Product[];
      @Output() onProductSelected: EventEmitter<Product>;

      constructor() {
        this.onProductSelected = new EventEmitter();
       }

      clicked(product: Product): void {
        this.currentProduct = product;
        this.onProductSelected.emit(product);
      }

      isSelected(product: Product): boolean {
        if(!product || !this.currentProduct) {
          return false;
        }
        return this.currentProduct.sku === product.sku;
      }
    }
```

ProductRowComponent

```
import { Component, Input, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../product';

@Component({
  selector: 'product-row',
  template: `
  <div class="card">
  <div  class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">{{product.name}}</h4>
     <p class="card-text">
      {{product.price}} 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
  `
})
export class ProductRowComponent {
  @Input() product: Product;
  @HostBinding('attr.class') cssClass = "selectedItem";
}
```

I defined the style

```
.selectedItem  {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

But it is not apply right style to the selected product. I debugged browser window and have seen the style is applied to the host element product-row.

```
**<product-row** ng-reflect-product="[object Object]" **class="selectedItem"**>
  <div class="card">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Black Running Shoes</h4>
    <p class="card-text">
      109.99 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</product-row>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: where did you declared your css class `selectedItem  `

Comment: I declared in style.css

Answer (score 0):

You should use attribute directive with @HostBinding inside for this purpose, not component.